# checkbox values not saving when end users click multiple boxes fast

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am having an issue where users are rapidly checking minor projects as complete and they are clicking some of the boxes milliseconds apart which results in the values not saving. I am unsure of how to best proceed as I am not sure of the problem. The clicks save if they slow down but logs don't indicate any error's when they speed up.

Checkbox using primefaces:

```
<p:column styleClass="datatable-column-small" sortBy="#{task.complete}" headerText="Complete">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="panel-group-center">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{task.complete}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.toggleCheckbox(task)}" update="@form "/>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </h:panelGroup>     
</p:column>
```

Bean:

```
public void toggleCheckbox(VerificationTaskEntity task) {
        if (isReadyForTaskUpdate()) {
            logger.info("Task checkbox updated");
            
            // check if task is complete and remove simulated and follow up date if so - also prevents inputs in these fields if complete
            if (task.isComplete() == true) {
                task.setSimulated(false);
                task.setFollowUpDate(null);
            }           
            else if (task.getSimulated() != null && task.getFollowUpDate() == null) {
                // check if task was set to simulated and automatically set a follow-up date if so
                if(task.getSimulated() == true) {   task.setFollowUpDate(new Date());}
                else {  task.setFollowUpDate(null);}            
            }
            
            getTaskService().updateTask(task);
        }
        else {
            String warnMessage = "Project not ready for verification. Please update required fields in project.";
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,WARN_SUMMARY,warnMessage));          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have to say, don't know anything about _primefaces_, however from looking at your code and reading the issue I suspect the problem is that the 'fast clicking' users are hitting your code within the `if (isReadyForTaskUpdate())` block, therefore won't be caught by the catch. Does that make sense? To check you could put an 'inner try/catch block within the if?

Comment: There is a roundabout time where the view will update and pull values - causing JSF to reload the section of the view containing the form in this case. This can happen during user interaction. If you update the whole form, this is exactly what you would expect. In this specific case you have a listener directly on the ajax tag so I think `update="@this"` should solve it in your specific case. Without seeing more of the code I don't know if that's going to work for you though.

Comment: Imagine this sequence of events. 1. The ajax request fires. 2. JSF starts updating the view and at the instant the user happens to click on another checkbox. 3. Because of `update="@form"` the whole form updates - overwriting the interaction from the user.

Answer (score 1):

Adam in the comments section is spot on. An easy oversight on my part. I corrected the code to reflect the proper instance to be updated.

```
<p:column styleClass="datatable-column-small" sortBy="#{task.complete}" headerText="Complete">
    <h:panelGroup styleClass="panel-group-center">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{task.complete}">
            <p:ajax listener="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.toggleCheckbox(task)}" update="@this "/>
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </h:panelGroup>     
</p:column>
```

A big thanks to Adam for this as I kept looking more at the backend code rather than the obvious issue on the front-end method.